# What's wrong with my MySQL code here in varchar(max) line?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
create table snippet(
  id int not null auto_increment,
  primary key(id),
  idlanguage int not null,
  foreign key(idlanguage) references language(id),
  iduser int not null,
  foreign key(iduser) references user(id),
  title varchar(200) not null,
  content varchar(max) not null,
  rating int,
  creationdate datetime
);
```

I'm getting an error at line 9 near 'max)' according to PHPMyAdmin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`VARCHAR(MAX)` is an MS SQL Server extension to the SQL language -- it does not exist in mysql.  Put a number there and you will be golden.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that "`max`" is a valid value for the maximum number of character that can be put in your `content` column : you should specify a numerical value.

But note that `varchar` has a limited maximum length *(see the [`varchar` page in the MYSQL's manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/char.html) for the details)* -- which means it might not be the best data-type for a "`content`" column.

A possibibly better solution might be to use one of the `TEXT` data-type :

```
...
content TEXT not null, 
...
```

`TEXT` columns can contain strings that are a lot longer than varchar ; for more informations, see [10.4.3. The BLOB and TEXT Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/blob.html).

Comment: @Lex I was just searching through the manual for the exact value when you posted your comment -- I've edited my answer to remove the values, and put a link to the manual ;; basically, the maximum size of a varchar depends on the size of the other columns of the row, it seems.